# Theorem won't go to multiple lines and is causing text to run off the page

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am writing a paper for a class that has to include a proof.  I have started out by listing what I want to prove as a theorem and then I'll go through the process of proving it.  However, the code I am using below puts everything on one line and the text portion of the theorem ends up running off the page.  I tried putting in "\" after the equation to put the text onto the line below it but that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas as to how I can fix this issue?

```
\begin{theorem}  
\[  
G(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}C_kx^k=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x},\\ 
where G(x) is the generating function for the catalan number sequence.  
\]  
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: One can't have line breaks in a single-line displayed equation. Incidentally, why would you wish to place `where G(x) is the generating function for the catalan number sequence.` inside the displayed equation?

Comment: you can not have linebreaks (`\\ `) in a displayed equation (`\[ \]`) nor can you have words of text, move `where...` out of the math display

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't place the string `where G(x) is the generating function for the catalan number sequence.` inside a displayed equation. Second, one cannot have line breaks inside `\[ ... \]`. If you need to create a multi-line displayed equation, use a suitable environment provided by the `amsmath` package, such as `align`, `gather`, and `multline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}  
Bla bla bla \dots
\[  
G(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}C_kx^k=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\,,
\]  
where $G(x)$ is the generating function for the catalan number sequence.  
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know that this was an option, I'm still new to Latex so I'm figuring most things out as I go.  Thank you very much for the input, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you really wish the "where G(x) is the generating function for the catalan number sequence"-phrase to belong to the equation, which would affect the vertical spacing/the size of the vertical gap between the equation and that phrase, you can, e.g., use a `gather`- or a `split`-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\begin{gather*}
G(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}C_kx^k=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x},\\
\text{where \(G(x)\) is the generating function for the catalan number sequence.}%
\end{gather*}
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
&G(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}C_kx^k=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x},\\
&\text{where \(G(x)\) is the generating function for the catalan number sequence.}%
\end{split}\end{equation*}
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And in some situations a simple `minipage`-environment might be your friend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\[%
G(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}C_kx^k=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x},
\text{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}%
  where \(G(x)\) is the generating function for the catalan number sequence.%
  \end{minipage}%
}%
\]
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\parshape` inside `minipage`, you can achieve things that are even more funny:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\[%
\boxed{%
  G(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}C_kx^k=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x},
  \text{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1.9cm}%
    \parshape 3 0cm 1.9cm 0cm 1.9cm -5.2cm 7.1cm
    where \(G(x)\) is the generating function for the catalan number sequence.%
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
}%
\]
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]